# Allowing a fixed vertical menu to scroll after a certain length is reached

Tags: jquery, menu

I have an in-page navigation menu that switches to a fixed position as you scroll down via the following code I appropriated from somewhere else:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
          var top = $('#toc2').offset().top - parseFloat($('#toc2').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));

$(window).scroll(function (event) {
// what the y position of the scroll is
var y = $(this).scrollTop();

// whether that's below the form
if (y >= top) {
  // if so, add the fixed class
  $('#toc2').addClass('fixed');

} 

else {
  // otherwise remove it
  $('#toc2').removeClass('fixed');
}
 });
});
```

CSS styles:

```
#toc2Wrapper { 
 left: 960px;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
font-size:11px;

}

#toc2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 background: #FFF;
 padding:3px;
 width: 200px;
 border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
}

#toc2.fixed {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 }
```

My problem is that the in-page nav, by the nature of the page content, can become quite large if multiple items are toggled within the menu. This means the length of the menu can reach beyond the bottom of the window and become unreachable due to the fixed position script (unless other sections are collapsed again).

Rather than rely on a one-section-at-a-time accordion menu, I want to be able to let the menu scroll inside of itself or be allowed to become unfixed from the top of the window if the bottom extends beyond the bottom of the window.

Android's website has good example of what I'm trying to achieve. Expand "App Components" in a relatively short window and a scroll bar appears for the menu:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

How can I modify the existing script to allow something like this?

Comment: Have you tried modifying the CSS to give the body of the page a height of 100% and the entire menu container has a height of 100% then making that same menu container have an overflow:scroll-x?

Comment: For future flexibility's sake I'd rather not be dependent on something related to the entire page layout as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You can measure and compare window height and #toc2 height within your function before adding the fixed div class

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
  // what the y position of the scroll is
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();

  // get your window and toc heights
  var windowheight = $(this).height();
  var tocheight = $('#toc2').height();

  // compare heights
  if(windowheight > tocheight) {
    // only runs add/remove fixed if window height is greater than #toc2
    if (y >= top) {
      // if so, add the fixed class
      $('#toc2').addClass('fixed');
      } 
  else {
    // otherwise remove it
    $('#toc2').removeClass('fixed');
    }
   }
 });
```